# Windows Form - Override Enter with an other key

Tags: winforms, focus, overriding

Is there a way in Windows Form to activate the currently focused button/control with the Q key? Or override the Enter, so that pressing Q activates the currently focused control like Enter does? I want the user to be able to control the application with just the left hand on Tab and Q to cycle controls and activate them.

```
private void Form2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Q)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
```

I already have this, but what do I need after the e.Handled to activate the current focus?

Comment: To move focus to different controls, `Tab` is enough. Do you mean you want to use `Q` instead of `Enter` on a `Button`? What about a `TextBox`?

Comment: The thing is, everything is automated you just have to make some decisions and press one of the buttons i have and it would be nice if the user could use the right hand for mouse control and the left one for Tab + Q to select a button and activate it, without using enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an option you can override [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) and check if the key is <kbd>Q</kbd> then send <kbd>Enter</kbd> using [`SendKeys.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx) and return `true` to indicate you that you processed the key:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Q)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{Enter}");
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

You can limit the behavior to buttons by checking `this.ActiveControl is Button`  if you need.

Comment: You are welcome :) You can limit the behavior to buttons by checking `this.ActiveControl is Button`  if you need.